# Prolog guitracer not working on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, prolog, swi-prolog

I tried what appears [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.prolog.swi/2504) but it does not work. I keep getting the following error `ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: guitracer/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)`

I tried running the command in the X11 terminal and in my iterm terminal.

Do you have any idea of how I could make it work ?

Comment: Try the version from **Macports**. `sudo port install swi-prolog`. It compiles with XPCE enabled (at least if you have XQuartz installed), and also contains the guitracer. If you compile it yourself and have the X11 development libraries installed, you probably need to specify some flags like `CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include`, `LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib` so that the compiler finds the X11 libraries.

Comment: I tried your solution, it works. Can you put your comment as an answer for me to label it as the solution please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the version from **Macports** with:

```
sudo port install swi-prolog
```

It compiles with XPCE enabled (at least if you have XQuartz installed), and also contains the guitracer. If you compile it yourself and have the X11 development libraries installed, you probably need to specify some flags like `CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include`, `LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib` so that the compiler finds the X11 libraries.